# Visual Studio for Mac azure remote debugging on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, azure, asp.net-web-api, remote-debugging, visual-studio-mac

The matter is pretty simple:
I'm on `Visual Studio for Mac` on `Mac OS X Sierra`, everything works perfectly and the deploy on `Azure` is great. 
The problem comes when I need to debug some odd error on the deployed remote app since it doesn't happen locally.

I guess it's related to some third-party web service call but I really cannot figure out from the log.

Comment: In my case, I'm trying to debug an error that occurs within my web app on Android devices. I'll update you with any info that I find.

Comment: Cloud Explorer and Server Explorer aren't currently a feature in Visual Studio for Mac. You might need to use Azure diagnostics logs if there's no IDE support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

@Mikejo5000 answered me on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure (bottom of the page)

Comment: Is this question about using Visual Studio for Mac? Or are you using Visual Studio 2017 installed in a Windows VM running on you Mac?